# Mqtt connection stuck on Reconnecting

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, iot, amazon-cognito

I am trying to connect to the Amazon IoT service using an android app following the guide on https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSubWebSocket.

I have change the CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT to the ENDPOINT value found in SETTINGS section of AWS IoT Console. Additionally I have changed the COGNITO_POOL_ID value to POOL_ID found under the *Getting Started with Amazon Cognito*.

Unfortunately now everytime I try to connect to the connect, even using the sample code form the above repo, the *Connection Status* is status keep on trying to *Reconnect* without providing any *throwable* object.

Comment: Hi Did you find any solution for this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the IoT thing policy did you give appropriate permissions to connect, subscribe and publish. The option can be found in AWS IoT->Security->Policy->Create Policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:293751794947:topic/replaceWithATopic"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above policy gives all access to the user. Also, make sure your pool which you created is for unauthenticated users.

**UPDATE**
In the IAM policies.Do check if you have given appropriate permissions to the cognito pool. If not attach the IoTFullAccess policy to the pool. It will solve the problem.